# Need help to get started integrating lua in c++ game

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, luabind

I need help integrating lua in my game. I know only a little about lua, since I just started learning scripting (in general). I've read tutorials about lua, but most of them are only tell me how to bind lua in c++ code (which I've managed to do that with LuaBind), or explaining features in lua.

Let's say I have a "Player" class and "Obstacle" class.
Obstacle class have these functions :

```
class Obstacle {
  // ... member vars

  // functions that will behave differently based on script :
  void onTouchPlayer(Player* player);
  void onUpdate(float deltaTime);
}
```

onTouchPlayer and onUpdate is meant to behave differently based on script.

What confuses me is what to write in the script, and how to call it in c++? If I already have Player class exported to Lua with LuaBind, how can I, for example, kill player at onTouchPlayer() and move the obstacle randomly at onUpdate function with lua?

Comment: You might try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of tutorials out there dealing with that. A [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=integrate+lua+and+c%2B%2B) will give you some.

I personally liked this one:

http://csl.sublevel3.org/lua/

Answer (score -1):

The following page of the Lua Development Guide (5.0) tells you how to call lua functions from the C environment.

http://www.lua.org/pil/25.2.html